# how to fetch the records having highest level in connect by oracle?? or the record having longest hierarchical path

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I would like to fetch the record having highest level in a table in oracle database using pl/sql.
for some keys it could be level 2 for some it could be level 6... I want to get the records with their highest level path.

can some one help or guide ?

Comment: Give some examples about your requirement.

Comment: And, by the way, is it ORACLE or MySQL?

Comment: that's oracle.. I thought I might get some idea(logic prospective) from MySQL hence the tag...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure even if the question is related to oracle but in oracle you can achieve this by doing something similar to your query.

```
select level 
from dual 
connect by level  < 11
order by level desc
```

Comment: no that's not working...its oracle query only but I can explain the scenario.. I have a table in which there are three columns.. ID,Level, Path now id is

Comment: Complete your scenario.

Comment: I am just new to this forum hence the draft left as it was... meanwhile I thought of something tried and it worked so could not complete the scenario... hope you wont mind to bear the newbie's mistakes here and yes... thank you so much for the quick response :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not very detailed, but I guess you mean the level in a hierarchical query with CONNECT BY?!

If so, you could just add the pseudo-column LEVEL to your query. Do

> ORDER BY LEVEL DESC

and just focus on the first few, which have your highest level with a

> rownum<10

(or ofc, something higher than 10, if you have multiple Leafs on the same level) in your WHERE-Clause.

For Example something like this should work:

> SELECT some_id, parent_id, foo, bar, level FROM tableX CONNECT BY PRIOR some_id = parent_id WHERE rownum<10 ORDER BY level;

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer I was trying to do something like this... here I can't post the table or example as it is very difficult to format the question... or data in table.. here goes my query :)

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP

AS
       SELECT Fncnl_Lctn_Key,
              LEVEL AS Lev,
              Src_Parnt_Fncnl_Lctn_Code,
              SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (Src_Fncnl_Lctn_Unqid, '/') PATH,
              Parnt_Fncnl_Lctn_Key,
              Src_Fncnl_Lctn_Unqid,
              Src_Fncnl_Lctn_Name
         FROM Fncnl_Lctn_Dim
   CONNECT BY (    PRIOR Fncnl_Lctn_Key = Parnt_Fncnl_Lctn_Key
               AND PRIOR Src_Fncnl_Lctn_Name = Src_Parnt_Fncnl_Lctn_Code)
     ORDER BY Fncnl_Lctn_Key, LEVEL DESC;
```

And then further selecting

```
SELECT *
    FROM Temp
   WHERE (Fncnl_Lctn_Key, Lev) IN (  SELECT fncnl_Lctn_Key, MAX (lev) AS LEV
                                       FROM Temp
                                   GROUP BY Fncnl_Lctn_Key)
ORDER BY Fncnl_Lctn_Key;
```

Comment: THanks for the prompt ands quick response I am posting question for the very first time here :)

Comment: You must thanks others rather than thanking yourself :-))))

Comment: that's what I did if u care to read the comment posted above. :)

Comment: I cared that's why i asked. You thanked your own post which means you are thankful to yourself. Be courteous to others who responded to their post,\

Comment: I wrote  "thanks for the quick response..." after posting my answer, so that people who could view the answer would read the comment posted below. anyways thank you so much for the efforts you took to write a solution for my question #withCourtesy :)